# Using SSRS Reports with MySQL

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

Currently I am using SSRS reports with MSSQL. Now I am changing my database from MSSQL to MySQL for cloud migration. On cloud I wont be having MSSQL installed. So is it possible to use SSRS reports(with MySQL datasource) without having MSSQL installed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where will you be installing your SSRS instance?

Comment: @iamdave That's what I was searching for. Found that SQL server is needed for using SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use and [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/odbc-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) Data Source in SSRS, I believe this is not allowed when using SQL Server Express.

Another option which requires SQL Server but is available on Express is to use the [add linked server stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). SSRS will obtain data from your SQL Server database, which you can setup to access your MySQL linked server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the issue is I wont be having SQL Server.